# Poor memcpy Performance on Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, memcpy, numa

We have recently purchased some new servers and are experiencing poor `memcpy()` performance. The `memcpy()` performance is 3x slower on the servers compared to our laptops.

**Server Specs**

- Chassis and Mobo: SUPER MICRO 1027GR-TRF
- CPU: 2x Intel Xeon E5-2680 @ 2.70 Ghz
- Memory: 8x 16GB DDR3 1600MHz

I am also testing on another server with slightly higher specs and seeing the same results as the above server.

**Server 2 Specs**

- Chassis and Mobo: SUPER MICRO 10227GR-TRFT
- CPU: 2x Intel Xeon E5-2650 v2 @ 2.6 Ghz
- Memory: 8x 16GB DDR3 1866MHz

**Laptop Specs**

- Chassis: Lenovo W530
- CPU: 1x Intel Core i7 i7-3720QM @ 2.6Ghz
- Memory: 4x 4GB DDR3 1600MHz

**Operating System**

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Scientific Linux release 6.5 (Carbon) 
$ uname -a                      
Linux r113 2.6.32-431.1.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Dec 12 13:59:19 CST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Compiler (on all systems)**

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.6.1
```

Also tested with gcc 4.8.2 based on a suggestion from @stefan. There was no performance difference between compilers.

**Test Code**

The test code below is a canned test to duplicate the problem I am seeing in our production code. I know this benchmark is simplistic but it was able to exploit and identify our problem. The code creates two 1GB buffers and memcpys between them, timing the memcpy call. You can specify alternate buffer sizes on the command line using: `./big_memcpy_test [SIZE_BYTES]`

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

class Timer
{
 public:
  Timer()
      : mStart(),
        mStop()
  {
    update();
  }

  void update()
  {
    mStart = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    mStop  = mStart;
  }

  double elapsedMs()
  {
    mStop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::milliseconds elapsed_ms =
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(mStop - mStart);
    return elapsed_ms.count();
  }

 private:
  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point mStart;
  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point mStop;
};

std::string formatBytes(std::uint64_t bytes)
{
  static const int num_suffix = 5;
  static const char* suffix[num_suffix] = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB" };
  double dbl_s_byte = bytes;
  int i = 0;
  for (; (int)(bytes / 1024.) > 0 && i < num_suffix;
       ++i, bytes /= 1024.)
  {
    dbl_s_byte = bytes / 1024.0;
  }

  const int buf_len = 64;
  char buf[buf_len];

  // use snprintf so there is no buffer overrun
  int res = snprintf(buf, buf_len,"%0.2f%s", dbl_s_byte, suffix[i]);
  
  // snprintf returns number of characters that would have been written if n had
  //       been sufficiently large, not counting the terminating null character.
  //       if an encoding error occurs, a negative number is returned.
  if (res >= 0)
  {
    return std::string(buf);
  }
  return std::string();
}

void doMemmove(void* pDest, const void* pSource, std::size_t sizeBytes)
{
  memmove(pDest, pSource, sizeBytes);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::uint64_t SIZE_BYTES = 1073741824; // 1GB
  
  if (argc > 1)
  {
    SIZE_BYTES = std::stoull(argv[1]);
    std::cout << "Using buffer size from command line: " << formatBytes(SIZE_BYTES)
              << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "To specify a custom buffer size: big_memcpy_test [SIZE_BYTES] \n"
              << "Using built in buffer size: " << formatBytes(SIZE_BYTES)
              << std::endl;
  }
  

  // big array to use for testing
  char* p_big_array = NULL;

  ////////////
  // malloc 
  {
    Timer timer;
  
    p_big_array = (char*)malloc(SIZE_BYTES * sizeof(char));
    if (p_big_array == NULL)
    {
      std::cerr << "ERROR: malloc of " << SIZE_BYTES << " returned NULL!"
                << std::endl;
      return 1;
    }
    
    std::cout << "malloc for " << formatBytes(SIZE_BYTES) << " took "
              << timer.elapsedMs() << "ms"
              << std::endl;
  }
  
  ////////////
  // memset
  {
    Timer timer;

    // set all data in p_big_array to 0
    memset(p_big_array, 0xF, SIZE_BYTES * sizeof(char));

    double elapsed_ms = timer.elapsedMs();
    std::cout << "memset for " << formatBytes(SIZE_BYTES) << " took "
              << elapsed_ms << "ms "
              << "(" << formatBytes(SIZE_BYTES / (elapsed_ms / 1.0e3)) << " bytes/sec)"
              << std::endl;
  }

  ////////////
  // memcpy 
  {
    char* p_dest_array = (char*)malloc(SIZE_BYTES);
    if (p_dest_array == NULL)
    {
      std::cerr << "ERROR: malloc of " << SIZE_BYTES << " for memcpy test"
                << " returned NULL!"
                << std::endl;
      return 1;
    }
    memset(p_dest_array, 0xF, SIZE_BYTES * sizeof(char));

    // time only the memcpy FROM p_big_array TO p_dest_array
    Timer timer;

    memcpy(p_dest_array, p_big_array, SIZE_BYTES * sizeof(char));
    
    double elapsed_ms = timer.elapsedMs();
    std::cout << "memcpy for " << formatBytes(SIZE_BYTES) << " took "
              << elapsed_ms << "ms "
              << "(" << formatBytes(SIZE_BYTES / (elapsed_ms / 1.0e3)) << " bytes/sec)"
              << std::endl;

    // cleanup p_dest_array
    free(p_dest_array);
    p_dest_array = NULL;
  }

  ////////////
  // memmove
  {
    char* p_dest_array = (char*)malloc(SIZE_BYTES);
    if (p_dest_array == NULL)
    {
      std::cerr << "ERROR: malloc of " << SIZE_BYTES << " for memmove test"
                << " returned NULL!"
                << std::endl;
      return 1;
    }
    memset(p_dest_array, 0xF, SIZE_BYTES * sizeof(char));

    // time only the memmove FROM p_big_array TO p_dest_array
    Timer timer;

    // memmove(p_dest_array, p_big_array, SIZE_BYTES * sizeof(char));
    doMemmove(p_dest_array, p_big_array, SIZE_BYTES * sizeof(char));
    
    double elapsed_ms = timer.elapsedMs();
    std::cout << "memmove for " << formatBytes(SIZE_BYTES) << " took "
              << elapsed_ms << "ms "
              << "(" << formatBytes(SIZE_BYTES / (elapsed_ms / 1.0e3)) << " bytes/sec)"
              << std::endl;

    // cleanup p_dest_array
    free(p_dest_array);
    p_dest_array = NULL;
  }


  // cleanup
  free(p_big_array);
  p_big_array = NULL;
  
  return 0;
}
```

**CMake File to Build**

```
project(big_memcpy_test)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.0)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

# create verbose makefiles that show each command line as it is issued
set( CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON CACHE BOOL "Verbose" FORCE )
# release mode
set( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release )
# grab in CXXFLAGS environment variable and append C++11 and -Wall options
set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x -Wall -march=native -mtune=native" )
message( INFO "CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS = ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}" )

# sources to build
set(big_memcpy_test_SRCS
  main.cpp
)

# create an executable file named "big_memcpy_test" from
# the source files in the variable "big_memcpy_test_SRCS".
add_executable(big_memcpy_test ${big_memcpy_test_SRCS})
```

**Test Results**

```
Buffer Size: 1GB | malloc (ms) | memset (ms) | memcpy (ms) | NUMA nodes (numactl --hardware)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Laptop 1         | 0           | 127         | 113         | 1
Laptop 2         | 0           | 180         | 120         | 1
Server 1         | 0           | 306         | 301         | 2
Server 2         | 0           | 352         | 325         | 2
```

As you can see the `memcpy()` and `memset()` on our servers are much slower than on our laptops.

**Varying buffer sizes**

I have tried buffers from 100MB to 5GB all with similar results (servers slower than laptop).

**NUMA Affinity**

I read about people having performance issues with NUMA so I tried setting CPU and memory affinity using `numactl` but the results remained the same.

Server NUMA Hardware:

```
$ numactl --hardware                                                            
available: 2 nodes (0-1)                                                                     
node 0 cpus: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23                                         
node 0 size: 65501 MB                                                                        
node 0 free: 62608 MB                                                                        
node 1 cpus: 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31                                   
node 1 size: 65536 MB                                                                        
node 1 free: 63837 MB                                                                        
node distances:                                                                              
node   0   1                                                                                 
  0:  10  21                                                                                 
  1:  21  10
```

Laptop NUMA Hardware:

```
$ numactl --hardware
available: 1 nodes (0)
node 0 cpus: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
node 0 size: 16018 MB
node 0 free: 6622 MB
node distances:
node   0 
  0:  10
```

Setting NUMA Affinity:

```
$ numactl --cpunodebind=0 --membind=0 ./big_memcpy_test
```

Any help resolving this is greatly appreciated.

**Edit: GCC Options**

I have tried compiling with different GCC options:

Compiling with `-march` and `-mtune` set to native

```
g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -march=native -mtune=native -O3 -DNDEBUG -o big_memcpy_test main.cpp
```

Result: Exact same performance

Compiling with `-O2` instead of `-O3`

```
g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -march=native -mtune=native -O2 -DNDEBUG -o big_memcpy_test main.cpp
```

Result: Exact same performance

**Edit: Changing `memset()` to write 0xF instead of 0 to avoid NULL page**

Result: Exact same performance

**Edit: Cachebench results**

In order to rule out that my test program is too simplistic I downloaded a real benchmarking program [LLCacheBench](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/projects/llcbench/cachebench.html).

I built the benchmark on each machine separately to avoid architecture issues. Below are my results.

[image: laptop vs server memcpy performance]

Notice the VERY large difference is performance on the larger buffer sizes. The last size tested (16777216) performed at 18849.29 MB/sec on the laptop and 6710.40 on the server. That's about a 3x difference in performance. You can also notice that the performance dropoff of the server is much steeper than on the laptop.

**Edit: `memmove()` is 2x FASTER than `memcpy()` on the server**

Based on some experimentation I have tried using `memmove()` instead of `memcpy()` in my test case and have found a 2x improvement on the server. `memmove()` on the laptop runs slower than `memcpy()` but oddly enough runs at the same speed as the `memmove()` on the server. This begs the question, why is `memcpy()` so slow?

Updated Code to test `memmove()` along with `memcpy()`. I had to wrap the `memmove()` inside a function because if I left it inline GCC optimized it and performed the exact same as `memcpy()` (I assume GCC optimized it to `memcpy()` because it knew the locations did not overlap).

Updated Results:

```
Buffer Size: 1GB | malloc (ms) | memset (ms) | memcpy (ms) | memmove() | NUMA nodes (numactl --hardware)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Laptop 1         | 0           | 127         | 113         | 161       | 1
Laptop 2         | 0           | 180         | 120         | 160       | 1
Server 1         | 0           | 306         | 301         | 159       | 2
Server 2         | 0           | 352         | 325         | 159       | 2
```

**Edit: Naive `memcpy()`**

I have implemented my own naive version of `memcpy()` and tested it:

`naiveMemcpy()` Source

```
void naiveMemcpy(void* pDest, const void* pSource, std::size_t sizeBytes)
{
  char* p_dest = (char*)pDest;
  const char* p_source = (const char*)pSource;
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeBytes; ++i)
  {
    *p_dest++ = *p_source++;
  }
}
```

`naiveMemcpy()` Results Compared to `memcpy()`:

```
Buffer Size: 1GB | memcpy (ms) | memmove(ms) | naiveMemcpy()
------------------------------------------------------------
Laptop 1         | 113         | 161         | 160
Server 1         | 301         | 159         | 159
Server 2         | 325         | 159         | 159
```

**Edit: Assembly Output**

Simple `memcpy()` source:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  size_t SIZE_BYTES = 1073741824; // 1GB
  
  char* p_big_array  = (char*)malloc(SIZE_BYTES * sizeof(char));
  char* p_dest_array = (char*)malloc(SIZE_BYTES * sizeof(char));
  
  memset(p_big_array,  0xA, SIZE_BYTES * sizeof(char));
  memset(p_dest_array, 0xF, SIZE_BYTES * sizeof(char));
    
  memcpy(p_dest_array, p_big_array, SIZE_BYTES * sizeof(char));
    
  free(p_dest_array);
  free(p_big_array);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Assembly Output: This is the exact same on both the server and the laptop.

```
        .file   "main_memcpy.cpp"
        .section        .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
        .p2align 4,,15
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB25:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movl    $1073741824, %edi
        pushq   %rbx
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
        .cfi_offset 3, -24
        subq    $8, %rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
        call    malloc
        movl    $1073741824, %edi
        movq    %rax, %rbx
        call    malloc
        movl    $1073741824, %edx
        movq    %rax, %rbp
        movl    $10, %esi
        movq    %rbx, %rdi
        call    memset
        movl    $1073741824, %edx
        movl    $15, %esi
        movq    %rbp, %rdi
        call    memset
        movl    $1073741824, %edx
        movq    %rbx, %rsi
        movq    %rbp, %rdi
        call    memcpy
        movq    %rbp, %rdi
        call    free
        movq    %rbx, %rdi
        call    free
        addq    $8, %rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        popq    %rbx
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        popq    %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE25:
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.6.1"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

**PROGRESS!!!! asmlib**

Based on suggestion from @tbenson I tried running with the [asmlib](http://www.agner.org/optimize/asmlib.zip) version of `memcpy()`. My results initially were poor but after changing `SetMemcpyCacheLimit()` to 1GB (size of my buffer) I was running at speed on par with my naive for loop!

Bad news is that the asmlib version of `memmove()` is slower than the glibc version, it is now running at the 300ms mark (on par with the glibc version of `memcpy()`). Weird thing is that on the laptop when I `SetMemcpyCacheLimit()` to a large number it hurts performance...

In the results below the lines marked with SetCache have SetMemcpyCacheLimit set to 1073741824. The results without SetCache do not call `SetMemcpyCacheLimit()`.

Results using functions from asmlib:

```
Buffer Size: 1GB  | memcpy (ms) | memmove(ms) | naiveMemcpy()
------------------------------------------------------------
Laptop            | 136         | 132         | 161
Laptop SetCache   | 182         | 137         | 161
Server 1          | 305         | 302         | 164
Server 1 SetCache | 162         | 303         | 164
Server 2          | 300         | 299         | 166
Server 2 SetCache | 166         | 301         | 166
```

Starting to lean towards cache issue, but what would cause this?

Comment: Are you compiling the test on the server?

Comment: Yes i'm compiling the test on the server. Both systems are using the same version of Scientific Linux. Both have the same version of glibc (2.12) and gcc (4.6.1).

Comment: Can you check the code it calls into for memcpy? My initial guess is that the maybe the server's malloc is aligned differently than the laptop's.

Comment: Try compiling your `main.cpp` on the command line with `g++ -Wall -O2 -mtune=native`. Consider upgrading GCC to 4.8.2

Comment: you don't seem to be compiling with any arch specific flags, you definitely should for this to be a fair test. that being said, this is definitely a memory limited operation, and it looks like the memory specs aren't really faster on the server, so there shouldn't be huge gains. the server should outperform the laptops only when its working from the cache or registers

Comment: oh also dont set all those pages to zero, set them to something else. linux is copy on write, and memset might be optimized with that in mind. it looks like you could just be pointing to the trivial null page which makes this whole test worthless.

Comment: @SteveCox I agree i shouldn't see huge gains by the servers, but i am concerned that the servers are slower than the laptops by a factor of 2-3x. Edit: i will try not memsetting the pages.

Comment: @nick no you have to memset the pages, but set them to some other value

Comment: hmm. it looks like you're measuring a throughput of about 8GB/s on the laptops memset. Which is pretty close to the theoretical limit of 12.8. I would expect the memcpy to take longer though (not sure if the memory controller can do it all on its own). If there is a full read and write involved in the memcpy implementation, then thats a bandwidth of 16 GB/s which exceeds the memory's theoretical limitations. Can someone confirm for me that memcpying 1GB is actually a 2GB operation?

Comment: @SteveCox Tried running memset's with a value of 0xF instead of 0. Got the same results.

Comment: Is the laptop memory buffered ECC DIMM like the server?

Comment: @stark Laptop memory us unbuffered DIMMS at 1600MHz. I am testing on two servers now, one about 6 months old with buffered DIMMS at 1600MHz and another one about 1 month old with buffered DIMMS at 1866MHz. Both servers exhibit the same performance. ECC is not enabled on either of the servers.

Comment: If you reduce the server memory to 4 x 4G doe it change the speed?  I'd guess the larger page tables have an effect.

Comment: Also is HT turned on for the server or the laptop?

Comment: @stark, yes HT is enabled on both machines. I currently don't have physical access to the server as it is located in a lab across country. I am going to our other site where the server lives in a few days, i will try adjusting RAM configuration then.

Comment: 1) Both are 64 bits SO?; 2) The server is inside a VM?

Comment: This might sound silly, but have you timed how long your timing takes on each machine? It isn't free.

Comment: Another thing to do is write a simple memcpy and memmove and compile them down and compare the assembly of them both, to see if there is any significant difference in the implementation or optimisation on the different machines.

Comment: I once came across a version of calloc that was just a for loop setting 4 bytes at a time, it was tragically slow...

Comment: @ctutte yes all machines are using the exact same 64 bit OS, exact same patch levels. Not running a VM anywhere, all bare metal. System load on all machines is 0,0,0 i am the one controlling these machines and can verify there is nothing going on in the background. This happens consistently.

Comment: @Salgar no i haven't timed my timings, but i would be very surprised if it takes 150ms to execute a timer. I will try a simplified memcpy and memmove implementation.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read it properly, yes, the timing will be insignificant at that size/time

Comment: Wow, this gets more and more interesting... I can't believe that your byte-by-byte `memcpy` runs *faster* than libc's!

Comment: @nick Can you try with the g++-4.8?

Comment: @stefan i am building with 4.6.1 (i will update question) are there significant memcpy improvements between 4.6.1 and 4.8.2?

Comment: @nick It's possible, I don't know ;-) The point is: it may be something the compiler does (or how the compiler was configured!), so it would be great to test with another compiler.

Comment: @stefan Compiled and ran with 4.4.7 (default compiler on RHEL 6.5) and no change. I am downloading 4.8.2, building that will take a while.

Comment: Go fetch [LIKWID](http://code.google.com/p/likwid/) and run the performance counter tool like this: `likwid-perfctr -C S1:0 -g MEM ./big_memcpy_test`. Also run `likwid-perfctr` with `numactl --membind=0` since `likwid-perfctr` does not support NUMA memory binding. It shows estimates of the memory speeds based on CPUs performance counters and also differentiates between local and remote memory access.

Comment: I'd love to see some assembly code (for each platform, since you compile natively). Maybe one uses AVX loops and the other uses `rep movs` flows?

Comment: Yes, please create a `main()` that just has a single large `memcpy` in it on both and generate the assembly output with `gcc/g++ -S` + all the same optimisations you've been using. The slow one must be doing something very odd if your custom byte by byte memcpy is so much faster. It should be much slower.

Comment: Have you checked your [memory alignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687210/gcc-memory-alignment-pragma)? If the [pipeline is stalling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_stall) on the server, then you'd expect memcpy performance to degrade.

Comment: @Salgar Added assembly outputs for laptop and server. The assembly was the exact same (diffed) i have posted the output to show what they both looked like. Nothing interesting going on.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i tried aligning to 16byte boundary using the link you provided. No change in memcpy performance however my naive implementation ran ~600ms on both laptop and server which is 2x slower on the server than regular memcpy and 6x slower on the laptop (compared to regular memcpy).

Comment: Based on suggestion from @stefan i have tried using a newer version of GCC, i chose 4.8.2 (the latest version). The performance numbers are exactly the same as with 4.6.1 in the original test.

Comment: @nick: Have you turned all the power-saving nonsense in the servers' BIOS off?

Comment: @nick I also tried pushing this to the Intel community forum (https://communities.intel.com/thread/50808). I have seen similar performance oddities with some tuned out-of-place matrix transpose functions. The optimized versions use cache blocking, which should improve performance (and make a transpose similar to a memcpy), but on the E5 series Xeons they are actually slower. That is not the case for Westmere Xeons or E3 Haswell Xeons.

Comment: @tbenson - as a first step, you should measure memory latency and bandwidth using, for example, [Intel's MLC](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intelr-memory-latency-checker) or TinyMemBench, or lmbench or whatever. Certainly the server parts have worse latency (as I described in my answer), but know how much will help. Furthermore several of those tools have separate tests for temporal and non-temporal stores.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[I would make this a comment, but do not have enough reputation to do so.]

I have a similar system and see similar results, but can add a few data points:

- If you reverse the direction of your naive `memcpy` (i.e. convert to `*p_dest-- = *p_src--`), then you may get much worse performance than for the forward direction (~637 ms for me). There was a change in `memcpy()` in glibc 2.12 that exposed several bugs for calling `memcpy` on overlapping buffers (http://lwn.net/Articles/414467/) and I believe the issue was caused by switching to a version of `memcpy` that operates backwards. So, backward versus forward copies may explain the `memcpy()`/`memmove()` disparity.
- It seems to be better to not use non-temporal stores.  Many optimized `memcpy()` implementations switch to non-temporal stores (which are not cached) for large buffers (i.e. larger than the last level cache). I tested Agner Fog's version of memcpy (http://www.agner.org/optimize/#asmlib) and found that it was approximately the same speed as the version in `glibc`. However, `asmlib` has a function (`SetMemcpyCacheLimit`) that allows setting the threshold above which non-temporal stores are used. Setting that limit to 8GiB (or just larger than the 1 GiB buffer) to avoid the non-temporal stores doubled performance in my case (time down to 176ms). Of course, that only matched the forward-direction naive performance, so it is not stellar.
- The BIOS on those systems allows four different hardware prefetchers to be enabled/disabled (MLC Streamer Prefetcher, MLC Spatial Prefetcher, DCU Streamer Prefetcher, and DCU IP Prefetcher). I tried disabling each, but doing so at best maintained performance parity and reduced performance for a few of the settings.
- Disabling the running average power limit (RAPL) DRAM mode has no impact.
- I have access to other Supermicro systems running Fedora 19 (glibc 2.17). With a Supermicro X9DRG-HF board, Fedora 19, and Xeon E5-2670 CPUs, I see similar performance as above. On a Supermicro X10SLM-F single socket board running a Xeon E3-1275 v3 (Haswell) and Fedora 19, I see 9.6 GB/s for `memcpy` (104ms). The RAM on the Haswell system is DDR3-1600 (same as the other systems).

**UPDATES**

- I set the CPU power management to Max Performance and disabled hyperthreading in the BIOS. Based on `/proc/cpuinfo`, the cores were then clocked at 3 GHz. However, this oddly decreased memory performance by around 10%.
- memtest86+ 4.10 reports bandwidth to main memory of 9091 MB/s. I could not find if this corresponds to read, write, or copy.
- The [STREAM benchmark](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/stream/) reports 13422 MB/s for copy, but they count bytes as both read and written, so that corresponds to ~6.5 GB/s if we want to compare to the above results.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was reading through the SuperMicro manual and noticed several settings for "energy efficiency" in the BIOS.  I'm wondering if one of those happens to be turned on na may be hurting performance?

Comment: @nick I will toggle the performance/efficiency settings tomorrow. I believe that setting the CPU scaling governors to performance mode (e.g. via `echo "performance" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuXX/cpufreq/scaling_governor` for core XX) will have a similar impact as well.

Comment: I tried running my code with asmlib version of memcpy and was able to reproduce your results. The default version of memcpy() had similar performance to glibc memcpy. When changing SetMemcpyCacheLimit() to 1GB the memcpy time came down to 160ms on the server! Unfortunately his memmove() implementation went up from 160ms to 300ms. This makes me think it is some sort of cache issue.

Comment: Updated my results using the asmlib versions of memmove and memcpy.

Comment: `memtest86+` should print COPY speed - [memtest86+-4.20-1.1/init.c line 1220](http://sources.debian.net/src/memtest86+/4.20-1.1/init.c?hl=1225#L1219) uses `memspeed((ulong)mapping(0x100), i*1024, 50, MS_COPY)` call. And `memspeed()` itself is implemented with [`cld; rep movsl`](http://sources.debian.net/src/memtest86+/4.20-1.1/init.c?hl=1412#L1411) with 50 iterations of copy loop over memory segment.

Comment: Yes, indeed, here is a [link](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=638477#c38) to a bug caused by this change to memcpy().

Comment: Wanted to point out that nontemporal stores are good for the rest of the program by not blowing out all the cache.

Answer (score 10):

This looks normal to me.

Managing 8x16GB ECC memory sticks with two CPUs is a much tougher job than a single CPU with 2x2GB. Your 16GB sticks are Double sided memory + they may have buffers + ECC (even disabled on motherboard level)... all that make data path to RAM much longer. You also have 2 CPUs sharing the ram, and even if you do nothing on the other CPU there is always little memory access. Switching this data require some additional time. Just look at the enormous performance lost on PCs that share some ram with graphic card.

Still your severs are really powerfull datapumps. I'm not sure duplicating 1GB happends very often in real life software, but I'm sure that your 128GBs are much faster than any hard drive, even best SSD and this is where you can take advantage of your servers. Doing the same test with 3GB will set your laptop on fire.

This looks like the perfect example of how an architecture based on commodity hardware could be much more efficient than big servers. How many consumer PCs could one afford with the money spent on these big servers ?

Thank you for your very detailed question.

**EDIT :** (took me so long to write this answer that I missed the graph part.)

I think the problem is about where the data is stored. Can you please compare this :

- test one : allocate two contiguous blocks of 500Mb ram and copy from one to the other (what you already done)
- test two : allocate 20 (or more) blocks of 500Mb memory and copy form the first to the last, so they are far away from each other (even if you cannot be sure of their real position).

This way you'll see how memory controller handle memory blocks far away from each other. I think that your data is put on different zones of memory and it requires a switching operation at some point on the data path to talk with one zone then the other (there's such issue with double sided memory).

Also, are you ensuring that the thread is bound to one CPU ?

**EDIT 2:**

There are several kind of "zones" delimiter for memory. NUMA is one, but that's not the only one. For example two sided sticks require a flag to address one side or the other. Look on your graph how the performance degrade with big chunk of memory even on the laptop (wich has no NUMA).
I'm not sure of this, but memcpy may use a hardware function to copy ram (a kind of DMA) and this chip must have less cache than your CPU, this could explain why dumb copy with CPU is faster than memcpy.

Comment: The ECC and buffering overhead, as well as probably different CAS latency, is a good explanation for the ~3% difference at small buffer sizes.  But I think the question's main concern is the far right side of the graph, where performance diverges by a factor of three.

Comment: This doesn't explain the poor system memcpy performance compared to naiveMemcpy. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10300382/414279 explains it with NUMA on the Supermicro boards. 
I'm for the 1x I7 is faster than  2x I5 explanation also. First 1x is faster than 2x, and I7 has better caches then the I5.

Comment: @bokan i am ensuring that everything is running on same CPU and NUMA controller using numactl. This binds the process to a CPU and NUMA controller that i specify. I have verified that they are connected together using the numactl --hardware command.

Answer (score 8):

It's possible that some CPU improvements in your IvyBridge-based laptop contribute to this gain over the SandyBridge-based servers.

1. [Page-crossing Prefetch](http://techreport.com/review/22835/review-intel-core-i7-3770k-ivy-bridge-processor/2) - your laptop CPU would prefetch ahead the next linear page whenever you reach the end of the current one, saving you a nasty TLB miss every time. To try and mitigate that, try building your server code for 2M / 1G pages.
2. Cache replacement schemes also seem to have been improved (see an interesting reverse engineering [here](http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/01/ivb-cache-replacement/)). If indeed this CPU uses a dynamic insertion policy, it would easily prevent your copied data from trying to thrash your Last-Level-Cache (which it can't use effectively anyway due to the size), and save the room for other useful caching like code, stack, page table data, etc..). To test this, you could try rebuilding your naive implementation using streaming loads/stores (`movntdq` or similar ones, you can also use gcc builtin for that). This possibility may explain the sudden drop in large data-set sizes.
3. I believe some improvements were also made with string-copy as well ([here](http://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?t=25411)), it may or may not apply here, depending on how your assembly code looks like. You could try benchmarking with [Dhrystone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhrystone) to test if there's an inherent difference. This may also explain the difference between memcpy and memmove.

If you could get hold of an IvyBridge based server or a Sandy-Bridge laptop it would be simplest to test all these together.

Comment: At the top of my post i report specs on two servers. Sever 1 is SandyBridge E5-2680, Server 2 is IvyBridge E5-2650v2. Both servers exhibit the same performance numbers.

Comment: @nick, Hmm, missed the v2 part. You would have thought they'd make the names more distinguishable... Ok, I stand corrected, although the 2nd bullet may very well look and behave differently between a server and a client products, as they have completely different "uncores", so it's still possibly applicable.

Comment: @Leeor - FWIW, using 2MB or 1G pages doesn't solve the prefetching issue: the prefetching logic still operates at the 4K granularity and indeed it's mostly looking at physical addresses (i.e., it doesn't know that the current stream happens to lie in a 2MB page and so it won't prefetch past the 4K boundary). That said, as recently as Ivy Bridge, there is a "next page prefetcher" that tries to at least partly get around this issue by rapidly re-starting prefetching when the access go into the next page. It isn't clear how it interacts with 2MB pages.

Answer (score 4):

I modified the benchmark to use the nsec timer in Linux and found similar variation on different processors, all with similar memory. All running RHEL 6. Numbers are consistent across multiple runs.

```
Sandy Bridge E5-2648L v2 @ 1.90GHz, HT enabled, L2/L3 256K/20M, 16 GB ECC
malloc for 1073741824 took 47us 
memset for 1073741824 took 643841us
memcpy for 1073741824 took 486591us 

Westmere E5645 @2.40 GHz, HT not enabled, dual 6-core, L2/L3 256K/12M, 12 GB ECC
malloc for 1073741824 took 54us
memset for 1073741824 took 789656us 
memcpy for 1073741824 took 339707us

Jasper Forest C5549 @ 2.53GHz, HT enabled, dual quad-core, L2 256K/8M, 12 GB ECC
malloc for 1073741824 took 126us
memset for 1073741824 took 280107us 
memcpy for 1073741824 took 272370us
```

Here are results with inline C code -O3

```
Sandy Bridge E5-2648L v2 @ 1.90GHz, HT enabled, 256K/20M, 16 GB
malloc for 1 GB took 46 us
memset for 1 GB took 478722 us
memcpy for 1 GB took 262547 us

Westmere E5645 @2.40 GHz, HT not enabled, dual 6-core, 256K/12M, 12 GB
malloc for 1 GB took 53 us
memset for 1 GB took 681733 us
memcpy for 1 GB took 258147 us

Jasper Forest C5549 @ 2.53GHz, HT enabled, dual quad-core, 256K/8M, 12 GB
malloc for 1 GB took 67 us
memset for 1 GB took 254544 us
memcpy for 1 GB took 255658 us
```

For the heck of it, I also tried making the inline memcpy do 8 bytes at a time.
On these Intel processors it made no noticeable difference.  Cache merges all of the byte operations into the minimum number of memory operations.  I suspect the gcc library code is trying to be too clever.

Answer (score 4):

The numbers make sense to me. There are actually two questions here, and I'll answer them both.

First though, we need to have a mental model of how large<sup>1</sup> memory transfers work on something like a modern Intel processor. This description is *approximate* and the details may change somewhat from architecture to architecture, but the high level ideas are quite constant.

1. When a load misses in the `L1` data cache, a *line buffer* is allocated which will track the miss request until it is filled. This may be for a short time (a dozen cycles or so) if it hits in the `L2` cache, or much longer (100+ nanoseconds) if it misses all the way to DRAM.
2. There are a limited number of these line buffers *per core*<sup>1</sup>, and once they are full, further misses will stall waiting for one.
3. Other than these fill buffers used for *demand*<sup>3</sup> loads/stores there are additional buffers for memory movement between DRAM and L2 and lower level caches used by prefetching.
4. The memory subsystem itself has a *maximum bandwidth limit*, which you'll find conveniently listed on ARK. For example, the 3720QM in the Lenovo laptop shows a limit of [25.6 GB](https://ark.intel.com/products/64891/Intel-Core-i7-3720QM-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_60-GHz). This limit is basically the product of the effective frequency (`1600 Mhz`) times 8 bytes (64-bits) per transfer times the number of channels (2): `1600 * 8 * 2 = 25.6 GB/s`. The server chip on the hand has a peak bandwidth of [51.2 GB/s](http://ark.intel.com/products/64583/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2680-20M-Cache-2_70-GHz-8_00-GTs-Intel-QPI), per socket, for a total system bandwidth of ~102 GB/s.

   Unlike other processor features, there are often only a possible theoretical bandwidth numbers across the whole variety of chips, since
   it depends only on the noted values which are often the same across many
   different chips, and even across architectures. It is unrealistic
   expect DRAM to deliver at exactly the theoretic rate (due to various
   low level concerns, discussed a bit
   [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/250967/DD)), but you can often get
   around 90% or more.

So the primary consequence of (1) is that you can treat misses to RAM as a kind of request response system. A miss to DRAM allocates a *fill buffer* and the buffer is released when the request comes back. There are only 10 of these buffers, per CPU, for demand misses, which puts a **strict limit** on the demand memory bandwidth a single CPU can generate, as a function of its latency.

For example, lets say your `E5-2680` has a latency to DRAM of 80ns. Every request brings in a 64 byte cache line, so you just issued requests serially to DRAM you'd expect a throughput of a paltry `64 bytes / 80 ns = 0.8 GB/s`, and you'd cut that in half again (at least) to get a `memcpy` figure since it needs to read *and* write. Luckily, you can your 10 line-fill buffers, so you can overlap 10 concurrent requests to memory and increase the bandwidth by a factor of 10, leading to a theoretical bandwidth of 8 GB/s.

If you want to dig into even more details, [this thread](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/595220#comment-1843247) is pretty much pure gold. You'll find that facts and figures from [John McCalpin, aka "Dr Bandwidth](http://sites.utexas.edu/jdm4372) will be a common theme below.

So let's get into the details and answer the two questions...

### Why is memcpy so much slower than memmove or hand rolled copy on the server?

You showed that you the laptop systems do the `memcpy` benchmark in about **120 ms**, while the server parts take around **300 ms**. You also showed that this slowness mostly is not fundamental since you were able to use `memmove` and your hand-rolled-memcpy (hereafter, `hrm`) to achieve a time of about **160 ms**, much closer (but still slower than) the laptop performance.

We already showed above that for a single core, the bandwidth is limited by the total available concurrency and latency, rather than the DRAM bandwidth. We expect that the server parts may have a longer latency, but not `300 / 120 = 2.5x` longer!

The answer lies in **streaming (aka non-temporal) stores**. The libc version of `memcpy` you are using uses them, but `memmove` does not. You confirmed as much with your "naive" `memcpy` which also doesn't use them, as well as my configuring `asmlib` both to use the streaming stores (slow) and not (fast).

The streaming stores hurt the *single CPU* numbers because:

- **(A)** They prevent prefetching from bringing in the to-be-stored lines into the cache, which allows more concurrency since the prefetching hardware has other dedicated buffers beyond the 10 *fill buffers* that demand load/stores use.
- **(B)** The E5-2680 is known to be [particularly slow](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/456184#comment-1751849) for streaming stores.

Both issues are better explained by quotes from John McCalpin in the above linked thread. On the topic of prefetch effectiveness and streaming stores [he says](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/456184#comment-1751480):

> With "ordinary" stores, L2 hardware prefetcher can fetch lines in
>   advance and reduce the time that the Line Fill Buffers are occupied,
>   thus increasing sustained bandwidth.  On the other hand, with
>   streaming (cache-bypassing) stores, the Line Fill Buffer entries for
>   the stores are occupied for the full time required to pass the data to
>   the DRAM controller.   In this case, the *loads* can be accelerated by
>   hardware prefetching, but the stores cannot, so you get some speedup,
>   but not as much as you would get if both loads and stores were
>   accelerated.

... and then for the apparently much longer latency for streaming stores on the E5, [he says](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/456184#comment-1751849):

> The simpler "uncore" of the Xeon E3 could lead to significantly lower
>   Line Fill Buffer occupancy for streaming stores.  The Xeon E5 has a
>   much more complex ring structure to navigate in order to hand off the
>   streaming stores from the core buffers to the memory controllers, so
>   the occupancy might differ by a larger factor than the memory (read)
>   latency.

In particular, Dr. McCalpin measured a ~1.8x slowdown for E5 compared to a chip with the "client" uncore, but the 2.5x slowdown the OP reports is consistent with that since the 1.8x score is reported for STREAM TRIAD, which has a 2:1 ratio of loads:stores, while `memcpy` is at 1:1, and the stores are the problematic part.

This doesn't make streaming a bad thing - in effect, you are trading off latency for smaller total bandwidth consumption. You get less bandwidth because you are concurrency limited when using a single core, but you avoid all the read-for-ownership traffic, so you would likely see a (small) benefit if you ran the test simultaneously on all cores.

So far from being an artifact of your software or hardware configuration, the exact same slowdowns have been reported by other users, with the same CPU.

### Why is the server part *still* slower when using ordinary stores?

Even after correcting the non-temporal store issue, you are *still* seeing roughly a `160 / 120 = ~1.33x` slowdown on the server parts. What gives?

Well it's a common fallacy that server CPUs are faster in all respects faster or at least equal to their client counterparts. It's just not true - what you are paying for (often at $2,000 a chip or so) on the server parts is mostly (a) more cores (b) more memory channels (c) support for more total RAM (d) support for "enterprise-ish" features like ECC, virutalization features, etc<sup>5</sup>.

In fact, latency-wise, server parts are usually only equal or slower to their client<sup>4</sup> parts. When it comes to memory latency, this is especially true, because:

- The server parts have a more scalable, but complex "uncore" that often needs to support many more cores and consequently the path to RAM is longer.
- The server parts support more RAM (100s of GB or a few TB) which often requires [electrical buffers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_memory) to support such a large quantity.
- As in the OP's case server parts are usually multi-socket, which adds cross-socket coherence concerns to the memory path.

So it is typical that server parts have a latency 40% to 60% longer than client parts. For the E5 you'll probably find that ~80 ns is a [typical latency](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/509237#comment-1785907) to RAM, while client parts are closer to 50 ns.

So anything that is RAM latency constrained will run slower on server parts, and as it turns out, `memcpy` *on a single core* is latency constrained. that's confusing because `memcpy` *seems* like a bandwidth measurement, right? Well as described above, a single core doesn't have enough resources to keep enough requests to RAM in flight at a time to get close to the RAM bandwidth<sup>6</sup>, so performance depends directly on latency.

The client chips, on the other hand, have both lower latency and lower bandwidth, so one core comes much closer to saturating the bandwidth (this is often why streaming stores are a big win on client parts - when even a single core can approach the RAM bandwidth, the 50% store bandwidth reduction that stream stores offers helps a lot.

### References

There are lots of good sources to read more on this stuff, here are a couple.

- [A detailed description of memory latency components](https://sites.utexas.edu/jdm4372/2011/03/10/memory-latency-components/)
- [Lots of memory latency results](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/) across CPUs new and old (see the `MemLatX86` and `NewMemLat`) links
- [Detailed analysis of Sandy Bridge (and Opteron) memory latencies](https://tu-dresden.de/zih/forschung/ressourcen/.../2014_MSPC_authors_version.pdf) - almost the same chip the OP is using.

---

<sup>1</sup> By *large* I just mean somewhat larger than the LLC. For copies that fit in the LLC (or any higher cache level) the behavior is very different. The OPs `llcachebench` graph shows that in fact the performance deviation only starts when the buffers start to exceed the LLC size.

<sup>2</sup> In particular, the number of *line fill buffers* has [apparently been constant at 10](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/595220#comment-1843247) for several generations, including the architectures mentioned in this question.

<sup>3</sup> When we say *demand* here, we mean that it is associated with an explicit load/store in the code, rather than say being brought in by a prefetch.

<sup>4</sup> When I refer to a *server* part here, I mean a CPU with a *server uncore*. This largely means the E5 series, as the E3 series generally [uses the client uncore](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-isa-extensions/topic/593626#comment-1839975).

<sup>5</sup> In the future, it looks like you can add "instruction set extensions" to this list, as it seems that `AVX-512` will appear only on the Skylake server parts.

<sup>6</sup> Per [little's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little's_law) at a latency of 80 ns, we'd need `(51.2 B/ns * 80 ns) == 4096 bytes` or 64 cache lines in flight at all times to reach the maximum bandwidth, but one core provides less than 20.

Answer (score 3):

The question was already answered [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22823641/1034717), but in any case, here is an implementation using AVX that should be faster for large copies if that's what you are worried about:

```
#define ALIGN(ptr, align) (((ptr) + (align) - 1) & ~((align) - 1))

void *memcpy_avx(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n)
{
    char * d = static_cast<char*>(dest);
    const char * s = static_cast<const char*>(src);

    /* fall back to memcpy() if misaligned */
    if ((reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(d) & 31) != (reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(s) & 31))
        return memcpy(d, s, n);

    if (reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(d) & 31) {
        uintptr_t header_bytes = 32 - (reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(d) & 31);
        assert(header_bytes < 32);

        memcpy(d, s, min(header_bytes, n));

        d = reinterpret_cast<char *>(ALIGN(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(d), 32));
        s = reinterpret_cast<char *>(ALIGN(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(s), 32));
        n -= min(header_bytes, n);
    }

    for (; n >= 64; s += 64, d += 64, n -= 64) {
        __m256i *dest_cacheline = (__m256i *)d;
        __m256i *src_cacheline = (__m256i *)s;

        __m256i temp1 = _mm256_stream_load_si256(src_cacheline + 0);
        __m256i temp2 = _mm256_stream_load_si256(src_cacheline + 1);

        _mm256_stream_si256(dest_cacheline + 0, temp1);
        _mm256_stream_si256(dest_cacheline + 1, temp2);
    }

    if (n > 0)
        memcpy(d, s, n);

    return dest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Server 1 Specs
>
> - CPU: 2x Intel Xeon E5-2680 @ 2.70 Ghz
>
> Server 2 Specs
>
> - CPU: 2x Intel Xeon E5-2650 v2 @ 2.6 Ghz

According to Intel ARK, both the [E5-2650](https://www.google.com/search?q=intel+ark+E5-2650) and [E5-2680](https://www.google.com/search?q=intel+ark+E5-2680) have AVX extension.

> CMake File to Build

This is part of your problem. CMake chooses some rather poor flags for you. You can confirm it by running `make VERBOSE=1`.

You should add both `-march=native` and `-O3` to your `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`. You will likely see a dramatic performance increase. It should engage the AVX extensions. Without `-march=XXX`, you effectively get a minimal i686 or x86_64 machine. Without `-O3`, you don't engage GCC's vectorizations.

I'm not sure if GCC 4.6 is capable of AVX (and friends, like BMI). I know GCC 4.8 or 4.9 is capable because I had to hunt down an alignment bug that was causing a segfault when GCC was outsourcing memcpy's and memset's to the MMX unit. AVX and AVX2 allow the CPU to operate on 16-byte and 32-byte blocks of data at a time.

If GCC is missing an opportunity to send aligned data to the MMX unit, it may be missing the fact that data is aligned. If your data is 16-byte aligned, then you might try telling GCC so it knows to operate on fat blocks. For that, see GCC's [`__builtin_assume_aligned`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html). Also see questions like [How to tell GCC that a pointer argument is always double-word-aligned?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9608171/608639)

This also looks a little suspect because of the `void*`. Its kind of throwing away information about the pointer. You should probably keep the information:

```
void doMemmove(void* pDest, const void* pSource, std::size_t sizeBytes)
{
  memmove(pDest, pSource, sizeBytes);
}
```

Maybe something like the following:

```
template <typename T>
void doMemmove(T* pDest, const T* pSource, std::size_t count)
{
  memmove(pDest, pSource, count*sizeof(T));
}
```

Another suggestion is to use `new`, and stop using `malloc`. Its a C++ program and GCC can make some assumptions about `new` that it cannot make about `malloc`. I believe some of the assumptions are detailed in GCC's option page for the built-ins.

Yet another suggestion is to use the heap. Its always 16-byte aligned on typical modern systems. GCC should recognize it can offload to the MMX unit when a pointer from the heap is involved (sans the potential `void*` and `malloc` issues).

Finally, for a while, Clang was not using the native CPU extensions when using `-march=native`. See, for example, [Ubuntu Issue 1616723, Clang 3.4 only advertises SSE2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1616723), [Ubuntu Issue 1616723, Clang 3.5 only advertises SSE2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1616729), and [Ubuntu Issue 1616723, Clang 3.6 only advertises SSE2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1616731).